# Getting the value of appended textboxes on change in JQUERY

Tags: jquery

Need Help.

How can I get the value of appended textboxes having the same classname ? Kindly find the code snippet.

JS :

```
var count = document.getElementsByName("emailId[]").length; //get the totol no. of contact no. elements
//function to add a new element for entering emailId 
$("#add-email-id").click(function () {
    $("#email-id-container").append('<div id="emailAddress_container_' + count + '" style="margin-top:8px"><input type="text" name="emailId[]"  id="email_address_' + count + '" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Enter Email address here" placeholder="example@example.com" size="30" onBlur="ValidateEmail(' + count + ');" class="emailId"><span><input class="username" id="username_' + count + '" name="username[]" value="username" /></span><span style="margin-left:8px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);"  class="delete-email-id" style="color:#F00;">(-)</a></span><span id="email_err_' + count + '"></span></div>');
    count++; //increment the counter as new contact element is being added.
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.emailId').change(function () {
        var usernameDiv = $(this).parent("div").find(".username").attr("id"); //get the div where the truncated username will be placed
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
        alert($("#" + usernameDiv).val());
        var emailAddress = $(this).val();
        var truncatedValue = emailAddress;
        var name = "";
        if (emailAddress.indexOf("@") != -1) {
            ///alert("@");      
            name = $.trim(emailAddress.split("@")[0]);
            //alert(name);
            if (name && name.search(/\s/) === -1) {
                var len = name.length;
                //alert(len);
                if (len > 4) {
                    truncatedValue = name.substring(0, 3);
                }
                usernameDiv.val(truncatedValue);
            } else {
                usernameDiv.val("username");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I need to get the value of the email_address field and then get the truncated value in the appropriate username field appended.

Comment: can you share the hetml??

Comment: <div id="emailAddress_container_0" style="margin-top:8px"></div>

Comment: this is only the html code used..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.emailId').change(function() {  //will not work for dynamic generated element
```

Change the above line of code to

```
$(document).on('change', '.emailId', function() {
```

Instead attach to event handler to document or make sure to call the .change event when the element is created.

Comment: but, the elements are created using append()

Comment: @support that is what called dynamic way of adding elements to html.